# Can't resolve getSignedUrl Promise in Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have been trying to debug a Google Cloud Function that should return a signedUrl for uploading a file to Google Cloud Storage.

I have an https cloud function:

```
exports.gcpSecureURL = functions.https.onCall((data, res) => {

    const bucketName = data.bucket;
    const fileName = data.filename;

    let signedUrl = generateV4UploadSignedUrl(bucketName, fileName)
        .then(value => {
            console.log("VALUE: ", value);
            return value
        })

    res.send(signedUrl) 
        
});
```

Value is never reached and signedUrl is always a Promise.

In the generateV4UploadSignedUrl function I have:

```
async function generateV4UploadSignedUrl(bucketName, fileName) {
    // These options will allow temporary uploading of the file with outgoing
    // Content-Type: application/octet-stream header.
    const options = {
      version: 'v4',
      action: 'write',
      expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
      contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    };
  
    // Get a v4 signed URL for uploading file
    const [url] = await storage
      .bucket(bucketName)
      .file(fileName)
      .getSignedUrl(options)
      
    return url;
  };
```

The param bucketName is correct and fileName is just the name of the file I want to upload so at the stage where I generate the url should not matter?

I don't get why the signedUrl() method is not returning anything at all. I changed the permission on my bucket to StorageAdmin for AllUsers and my function is set to allow unauthenticated.

There is a TypeError in generateV4UploadSignedUrl in the cloud function logs:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable
at generateV4UploadSignedUrl (/workspace/index.js:51:19)
```

I have no idea what is happening and the function logs seem pretty opaque. What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here.

First, you're using a [callable type function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), but you appear to be using it as if you are writing an [HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).  If you want to write a callable function, please be sure to review the documentation for that.  They work differently than HTTP functions.  With callable functions, you must return a promise with the data to send to the caller.  With HTTP functions, you invoke `res.send()` or equivalent to send a response after all the async work is complete.  Be sure you understand the difference between the two.

> Value is never reached and signedUrl is always a Promise.

`signedUrl` is always a promise because `generateV4UploadSignedUrl` is `async`, and all `async` functions always return a promise.  You will have to await the promise to get the resolved value from the promise.

Your function should use async/await, and look more like this:

```
exports.gcpSecureURL = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const bucketName = data.bucket;
    const fileName = data.filename;

    let signedUrl = await generateV4UploadSignedUrl(bucketName, fileName)
    console.log("VALUE: ", signedUrl);
    return signedUrl
        
});
```

While this might not do exactly what you want (be sure that the entire contents of `signedUrl` is what you want to send to the client), it should get you closer to what you want.